# Using two CSS register and login forms without overriding each other

Tags: html, css

I have two different forms that i wish to use on the one page.
One is my log in form on the side to log users in & the other is a register form on the main content section.They both have separate css style sheets.
How can i style both without them overriding each other in the css style sheets?Is there something simple I'am not thinking of?

```
*//CSS Form1*

#form 1 
input {etc}
text area{etc}

*//CSS Form2*
#form 2
input {etc}
text area{etc}
```

Comment: Why not just give them separate classes? You can always use multiple style sheets, you just need to ensure that you are not using the same class/id for multiple style sheets or have a conflict by trying to style some generic tag like "div" or "ul" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form id="reg">
    <input type="button" class="button" text="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<form id="login">
    <input type="button" class="button" text="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#reg .button {
    background-color:red;
    width:250px;
    height:100px;
}
#login .button {
    background-color:green;
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
}
```

## [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zhUr8/)

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple really.  In your HTML give a login form a `loginForm` id or something like that; and, give a registration form a `registrationForm` id:

```
<form id = "loginForm"></form>
<form id = "registrationForm"></form>
```

Then, from CSS, you access each form and descendants within:

```
#loginForm {

}

#loginForm > input[type="password"] {

}

#registrationForm {

}

etc.
```

Because login and registration forms are specific instances of an interface, I would use ids  instead of classes.  Besides in CSS, ids have a higher specificity compared to classes.